# XSD code of the given XML file

Tags: xml, xsd

What will the corresponding XSD and dtd code of the XML file. Having trouble with declaring the Attributes. Having trouble with complextype and the sequence as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xs:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="CatSchema.xsd">

    <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">

        <catalog_item gender="Men's">
            <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
            <price>39.95</price>
            <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
            </size>
        </catalog_item>

        <catalog_item gender="Women's">
            <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
            <price>42.50</price>
            <size description="Medium">
                <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
                <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
            </size>
        </catalog_item>

    </product>

</catalog>
```

Comment: can you please paste your xsd also here.

Comment: Are you sure you need a DTD as well? The XSD standard has largely replaced DTD's, certainly new developments are favouring XSD's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XSD would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2017 - Developer Bundle Edition (Trial) 15.0.0.7089 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <element name="catalog">
    <complexType>
      <sequence>
        <element minOccurs="0" name="product">
          <complexType>
            <sequence>
              <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="catalog_item">
                <complexType>
                  <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="item_number" type="string" />
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="price" type="decimal" />
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="size">
                      <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                          <element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="color_swatch">
                            <complexType>
                              <simpleContent>
                                <extension base="string">
                                  <attribute name="image" type="string" use="optional" />
                                </extension>
                              </simpleContent>
                            </complexType>
                          </element>
                        </sequence>
                        <attribute name="description" type="string" use="optional" />
                      </complexType>
                    </element>
                  </sequence>
                  <attribute name="gender" type="string" use="optional" />
                </complexType>
              </element>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="description" type="string" use="optional" />
            <attribute name="product_image" type="string" use="optional" />
          </complexType>
        </element>
      </sequence>
    </complexType>
  </element>
</schema>
```

[image]